# OpenGL depth sorting

Tags: sorting, opengl, transparency

I'm doing basic object transparency using depth sort. As depth i use distance (squared) from camera to every center of model's triangles, which i calculate as {(x1+x2+x3)/3, (y1+y2+y3)/3, (z1+z2+z3)/3}. Although result is almost fine, but there are some mistakes.

monkey head without sorting
[image: no sorting]

with sorting
[image: sorting]

Is there anything i can do about those errors?

Comment: Fixed-function or programmable pipeline?

Comment: fixed. i make distance array, then sort it and swap corresponding values in indices array, glDrawElements in the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to sort the triangles in a perfect way. Look at the examples at end of the [Transparency Sorting](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting) article on opengl.org wiki.

@kos:
Give a look at [Order Independent Transparency with Dual Depth Peeling](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10/opengl/src/dual_depth_peeling/doc/DualDepthPeeling.pdf) and [Alpha to Coverage](http://www.humus.name/index.php?page=3D&ID=61).

Comment: So still there's not a single solution to render arbitrary transparency properly?

Comment: @Kos: check http://www.yakiimo3d.com/2010/07/19/dx11-order-independent-transparency/ and http://blog.icare3d.org/2010/07/opengl-40-abuffer-v20-linked-lists-of.html

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have screen-aligned particles, sorting arbitrary triangles is really quite difficult. For a perfect result you have to start splitting triangles.

As @tibur says, you can get away with some simple approximations but [order-independent transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-independent_transparency) (OIT) is a decent solution too. It does however require OpenGL 3 era graphics features. I have an [implementation available on github](https://github.com/pknowles/oit), which shows some ways to make *exact* OIT quite fast.

It's worth taking a look at "[adaptive transparency](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=adaptive+transparency)", "[multi-layer alpha blending](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=multi-layer+alpha+blending&oq=multi-layer+alpha+blending)" and "[hybrid transparency](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=hybrid+transparency)". These are fast approximate solutions but give very good results for common scenes.

---

Some similar questions...

- [three.js point clouds, BufferGeometry and incorrect transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33695202/1888983)
- [glPoint Alpha Blending issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18731648/1888983)
- [OpenGL transparency not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30151134/1888983)
- [Model with transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18706871/1888983)
- [OpenGL transparency/translucency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6352908/1888983)
- [How do I make textures transparent in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/751840/1888983)
- [OpenGL Alpha blending and object independent transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16774372/1888983)
- [Transperency in modern games and other 3D applications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23321254/1888983)
- [Why doesn't alpha blending work in ortho?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7373277/1888983)

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically speaking, if you know something about the body it could help sorting.

For instance the faces of a cube can be depth sorted by barycenter (face center) alone. If the center of the square face A will be closer than the center of B, B will never have any part in front of A (again, for a cube.)

In fact, for a convex body, faces can be sorted by orientation alone.