# Efficient OIT techniques for planar geometry

Tags: opengl, glsl, after-effects

This question is the continuation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774372/opengl-alpha-blending-and-object-independent-transparency) one.I need to implement Order independent transparency(OIT) for planar object as it is done in Adobe AfterEffects.
Some of the methods used today are [depth peeling](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10/opengl/src/dual_depth_peeling/doc/DualDepthPeeling.pdf) ,  [linked lists](http://blog.icare3d.org/2010/07/opengl-40-abuffer-v20-linked-lists-of.html) ,ray casting etc. These are quite complex solutions which are essential for self overlapping and volumetric geometry.Now, in my case all the objects are planes. Isn't there a simpler way of doing it in such a scenario? I am looking into AfterEffects. It uses OpenGL 2.X so I think they use some more "trivial" technique.Can stencil buffer be of use here?

If someone is going to suggest layered approach - this is not an option as 2 or more transparent planes may intersect one into another so both depth and occluded geometry must be preserved.

Comment: If the objects are planes, it's much easier to just find all the intersections between them, cut them into pieces, and render them in order.

Comment: I know what you mean.But it can impact the performance; if I have a lot of these I have to calc intersections , create new polys , sort etc...

Comment: Go ahead and use glIntercept or gDEBugger or whatever on After Effects to see what it's doing. I guarantee you that it's not doing anything more than just submitting geometry in the right order and letting the GPU blend it. And that's assuming it's using the GPU for that at all.

Comment: Probably you are right.That's why AE is so slow...