# three.js point clouds, BufferGeometry and incorrect transparency

Tags: javascript, three.js, point-clouds, buffer-geometry

The problem: I have a point cloud with quite a lot of data points (around one million). When I apply transparency to the rendered points, the transparency somehow does not show what is behind the rendered points

[image: incorrect rendering]

As you can see in the example of the marked point, it does not show what it should, it is as if there is a problem with the buffering.

I use three.js to create a point cloud using the following "setup":

The renderer:

```
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: this.canvas,
    antialias: true
});
```

The material:

```
this.pointMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    uniforms: {
        time:       { type: "f", value: 1.0 }
    },
    vertexShader:   document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent,
    transparent:    true
});
```

The vertex shader:

```
attribute float size;
attribute float opacity;
attribute vec3 color;
varying vec3 vColor;
varying float vOpacity;

void main() {
    vColor = color;
    vOpacity = opacity;
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_PointSize = size * (500.0 / length(mvPosition.xyz));
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition; 
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
uniform float time;
varying vec3 vColor;
varying float vOpacity;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, vOpacity);
}
```

The geometry (where I left out the part where I populate the arrays):

```
var bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

var vertices = new Float32Array(vertexPositions.length * 3);
var colors = new Float32Array(vertexColors.length * 3);
var sizes = new Float32Array(vertexSizes.length);
var opacities = new Float32Array(vertexOpacities.length);

bufferGeometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
bufferGeometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors, 3));
bufferGeometry.addAttribute('size', new THREE.BufferAttribute(sizes, 1));
bufferGeometry.addAttribute('opacity', new THREE.BufferAttribute(opacities, 1));

this.points = new THREE.Points(bufferGeometry, this.pointMaterial);
this.scene.add(this.points);
```

I tried this with the built-in point material, where the same happens

```
this.pointMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    size: this.pointSize,
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.25
});
```

Is this a but, expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what did you expect to see in the marked (by red) area?

Comment: Have you tried to add parameters `depthTest:false` and `blending:THREE.AdditiveBlending` to the material ?

Comment: @gaitat: A correct representation of the vertices behind the transparent one in front.

Comment: @Atrahasis: Yes, I did that, as it is suggested as a workaround in another thread / question here on Stackoverflow. However it is only of limited use since I do not want adaptive blending and I want the depth test for non-transparent objects (I know I could find a workaround for that as well, but that would be a workaround because of a workaround, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the alpha blending equation works is that a source colour for geometry that is behind is covered by a destination colour for geometry that is in front. This means you need to render your transparent geometry in sorted order from back to front, so that geometry in front will correctly blend with geometry behind.

If all you have is transparent geometry then you can just disable depth testing, render in reverse depth sorted order, and it will work. If you have opaque geometry as well then you need to first render all opaque geometry normally, then disable depth writing (not testing) and render transparent geometry in reverse depth sorted order, then re-enable depth writing.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731648/glpoint-alpha-blending-issue/18732790#18732790%0A) are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305911/opengl-depth-sorting/28379807#28379807) answers to [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151134/opengl-transparency-not-working-properly/30151384#30151384) questions if you're interested in learning a bit more.

Comment: It's kind of a workaround, however I'll accept this because I have the feeling that if I don't, the question will stay open forever ;).