# Render 100k sprites with 0.1 opacity, transparent maps and smooth antialiasing

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have the  following setup (only relevant bits of code):

**Renderer**

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ 
    antialias: true, alpha: true, canvas: canvas 
});
```

**Textures**

```
dot: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./assets/images/dot.png')
```

**Material**

```
let material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    size: size,
    sizeAttenuation: true,
    color: color,
    map: textures.dot,
    // alphaMap: textures.dotAlpha,
    blending: THREE.NormalBlending, // THREE.MultiplyBlending
    transparent: true,
    alphaTest: 0.1,
    opacity: 0.3
});
```

**Point cloud** Usually I have 20 to 50 point clouds with 1k to 10k dots. What I see on screen it's a small fraction of theese.

```
pointCloud = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
```

**Adding points**

```
cfg.pointCloud.forEach(point => {
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
    vertex.x = point.x;
    vertex.y = point.y;
    vertex.z = point.z;
    geometry.vertices.push(vertex);
});
```

I have the following issues:

- Overlaping sprites tend to clip each other instead of rendering on top of each other. Thus I get a lot of points simply obscured
- If i use `material.alphaTest = 0.5`and `material.opacity:0.1` the edges of the sprites become very sharp loosing all antialiasing effect. When viewed from a distance they tend to render very poorly and disappear. I was expecting being able to render smooth borders. I'm using 512x512 png maps.
- When I move the camera away from the origin after a certain distance sprites tend to disappear.
- Low opacity values seem to make the dots disappear.

How can I improve this rendering? Is there any other way besides using sprites? I'm lacking the know-how needed to write a custom shader so I will appreciate anything that helps with improving this rendering.

Here are some sample images that showcase the troubles:

- Even though the blue dots density is much higher in the green zone they tend to be obscured. I belive this happens because the green and red dots are the first point clouds introduced to the scene. And they render on top of the blue ones.

[image]

- If I tilt the camera it seems that some dots suddenly get rendered because of a different depth index.

[image]

- If I increase the opacity of certain point clouds their sprites tend to be obscured by sprites with lower opacity. I was expecting some blending effect there.

[image]

- Most of the dots tend to be clustered and due to the rendering quircks most of them tend to dissapear

[image]

- Again some clipping effects from close up

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5668

Comment: I followed the link but it seems that the author was having rendering issues because of not using `material.alphaTest = value`. I tried changing the example with `BufferGeometry`. When I increase the number of sprites to 10k It already showcases the same problems as in my example. http://jsfiddle.net/z6nmto9e/

Comment: If you followed the thread, sorting of particles was removed from Three.js, that's one of your issues. The thread says you either need to sort them yourself or use THREE.Sprite

Comment: I was just playing with this right now. I saw this after my first comment. It seems to fix a bit the rendering. http://jsfiddle.net/adrian_moisa/8ane66d2/ . I will try in my code to see what happens.

Comment: @gman Thank you for the indications. Due to your comments I was able to dig further and find an useful answer in another question. See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a significant improvement in the rendering quality. I found [very good answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647853/three-js-depthwrite-vs-depthtest-for-transparent-canvas-texture-map-on-three-p). Also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33695202/three-js-point-clouds-buffergeometry-and-incorrect-transparency) had some good information.

I have added `depthWrite` and `depthTest` as false in the material.

```
let material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    size: size,
    sizeAttenuation: true,
    color: color,
    map: this._textures.dot,
    blending: THREE.NormalBlending,
    transparent: true,
    alphaTest: 0.1,
    opacity: 0.3,
    depthWrite: false,
    depthTest: false
});
```

The difference is significant:

[image]

[image]

Still I have to find a solution for the antialiasing issues. When far away from the camera, dots tend to totally dissolve and disappear as it is shown in this close-up.

[image]